# Zend Form How to group element like this?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I created a zend form. I want to make a group of elements that output html like this:

```
           <div class="form_wrapper">
                <div class="form_label">
                    <label class="txtlabel" for="salary_type">Salary type</label>
                    <span>*</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form_element">
                    <select class="jp_select" id="salary_type" name="salary_type">
                        <option>..1..</option>  
                        <option>2</option>  
                        <option>3</option>  
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="salary_min" class="txtinput" name="salary_min" value="Min" onfocus="if(this.value=='Min') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=('Min');">
                    <input type="text" id="salary_max" class="txtinput" name="salary_max"  value="Max" onfocus="if(this.value=='Max') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=('Max');">
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end .form_wrapper -->
```

My code:

```
 $this->addElement('select', 'salary_type', array(
            'label' => 'Salary type',
            'multiOptions' => $salary_types,
            'class'=>'jp_select'
        ));

        $this->addElement('text', 'salary_min', array(
            'label' => 'Min',
            'class'=>'txtinput'
        ));

        $this->addElement('text', 'salary_max', array(
            'label' => 'Max',
            'class'=>'txtinput'
        ));

$this->addDisplayGroup(array('salary_type','salary_min','salary_max'), 'salary_group');
```

How can I set decorators to have html output like above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you are not able to render that exact html structure with simple Decorators alone.
One way to solve this problem is by using the ViewScript Decorator within your displayGroup decorator stack. Within the view script, you are able to retrieve the individual elements by using `$this->element->getElements();` ($this->element is an instance of `Zend_Form_DisplayGroup`)

For example:

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(
    array('salary_type','salary_min','salary_max'), 
    'salary_group',
    array(
        'decorators' => array(
            array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'path/to/viewscript.phtml')),
        ),
    )
);
```

Haven't tried it myself, but it should work.

Comment: I've already found the answer, but thank you for your help :)

Comment: @eureka why don't you post what you found?! It should help somebody.